# How to store query result in array in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
  for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
    {
        $data=DB::table('for_test')
        ->where('for_test.id','=',$i)
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
    }
```

For every loop it selects a different row from ‘for_test’ table. But I cannot store them. How can I store them? As an example when I write

```
  foreach ($data as $datas) {
        echo $datas->name;
    }
```

How can I get three values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting your `$data` variable on every iteration of the loop. Instead, make `$data` an array and append to it:

```
$data = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $data[] = DB::table('for_test')
        ->where('for_test.id','=',$i)
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
}
```

But you might also be able to do this in a single query (although I suspect your code is just an example):

```
$data = DB::table('for_test')
    ->whereIn('for_test.id', [1, 2, 3])
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```